# How to translate curl command to urlfetch or request in general?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl, https

I'd like to issue an https request to an api from my gae-server, e.g. using urlfetch.
Example call is given as curl command.

```
curl <URL> \
  -u <USER_KEY>: \
  -d "infoa=123" \
  -d "infob='ABC" \
  -d "token=<SOME_TOKEN>" \
  -d "description=Test"
```

All I want to know is, what the HTTPS request would look like, so I can replicate it using [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests) documentation. Probably going about it wrong but I have used `--trace-ascii -` with curl but from the ouptut I still cannot 100% say what the request I am issuing looks like.
What aspect of an http-request do they translate to? Would it something like this work:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(
        url='<URL>',
        payload={user: <USER_KEY>, data: {infoa=123, infob=ABC, ...}},
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So: -u for user goes into the authorization header. basic encryption is base64. -d for data goes into payload. Different -d are concatenated with a simple ampersand.

```
   try:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   "Authorization": "Basic %s" % base64.b64encode(<some_private_user_authentication>)} # base64 or similar needs to be imported
        result = urlfetch.fetch(
            url='<URL of endpoint>',
            payload='infoa={}&infob={}&description=Test Transaction'.format(info_a,                                                                                         info_b),
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers=headers)
        print repr(result.content) # do things..

    except urlfetch.Error:
        logging.exception('Caught exception fetching url')
        print 'Caught exception fetching url' # do other things..
```